# c# how to open a binary file and store it in a 16 bit buffer

Tags: c#, binary, buffer

I am writing a program to do some image processing.  I am working with raw binary files and I need to write the data from the raw file to a 16 bit buffer.  I have almost got it but I am not quite sure how to make the conversion.  Here is my code thus far:

```
        Int16[] pixelBuffer;
        String inFile;
        String outFile;        

        /// Constructor. Allocates space for 3032x2016 16-bit values.
        /// <param name="inputFile">Name of the binary input file to be read.</param>
        /// <param name="outputFile">Name of the binary output file to be written.</param>
        public ColorCorrector(String inputFile, String outputFile)
        {
        this.inFile = inputFile;
        this.outFile = outputFile;
        this.pixelBuffer = new Int16[6112512];
        //I need to open the binary file 'inputFile' and store 16-bit values in pixelBuffer.

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: is the input file **just** the image data, i.e. 3032*2016 16-bit values? or is it a format with metadata etc?

Comment: @MarcGravell it is just raw image data without any metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (var inputStream = File.Open(inputFile))      
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(inputStream))      
{           
    int index = 0;
    while (inputStream.Position < inputStream.Length)
        pixelBuffer[index++] = reader.ReadInt16();      
}
```

Comment: i'm assuming that you meant pixelBuffer[index++] and with that this did exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

If you want the **best performance** I recommend that you read into a fixed size `byte[]` buffer (of maybe 64KB) using the FileStream class.

You can copy each buffer using unsafe code into your `Int16[]`. It's only going to take a couple of lines to do the copying and it will be fast because no shifts and casts and such are required. It is just a tight copy loop.

I'd estimate that BinaryReader is 10x slower or so. Modern CPUs love tight loops without branches and BinaryReader cannot provide that.

Comment: if you are mentioning `unsafe`, there is no need to *copy* the data - you can *pretend* (see the example in my answer)

Comment: The code that the OP posted shows that he expects the data to end up in a Int16[] that is to be stored somewhere. Not sure if he can restructure.

Comment: true, but the OP is *also* essentially asking how to get data in and out of a file; I think it is reasonable to challenge any and all assumptions in the question...

Answer (score 1):

If you need it all in-memory, you might as well use a raw `byte[]` buffer. You can *pretend* that is actually `short` / `ushort` via `unsafe`:

```
 byte[] raw = File.ReadAllBytes(inputPath);
 unsafe
 {
     fixed(byte* ptr = raw)
     {
         ushort* pixels = (ushort*)ptr;
         pixels[0] = 0; // <=== your changes, etc
     }
 }
 File.WriteAllBytes(outputPath, raw);
```

Notes: you might need to check what the *endianness* of the file is. I've gone `ushort` in the above because `ushort` causes less surprises for people using "shift" operations on values with the MSB set. If it doesn't actually represent a *number* (but is just: data), it is usually easier to think of it as unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [`System.IO.BinaryReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) as well as [`System.Drawing.Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx), those are probably what you are looking for.

You can make a `BinaryReader` from a `FileStream` and use the `ReadInt16()` method to read 16 bit integers from the stream.

Comment: You can only use BinaryReader if you know that the endianness matches. Frankly, it isn't really worth it - might as well just use Stream and some shift operations. Bitmap isn't a bad suggestion, **if** it is a fit for the image format